# NodeJS and Socket.io - Defining Server and sockets issue

Tags: php, node.js, curl, socket.io

This is probably a simple mistake. I have a nodejs server running socket.io, I have got everything to work within the server.

However, I want to be able to make a CURL post via PHP to the node server, and have it emit the data. I can make the server receive the request, but when I try to emit the data, I get an error saying that the socket is not defined.

This is obvious in my code. My question is, how do I require socket.io before I setup the server? Hopefully a segment my code will help explain my problem:

```
var http = require('http')
, url = require('url')
, fs = require('fs')
, server;

server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
// your normal server code
var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
switch (path){
   case '/':
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
     res.write('<h1>Hello! <a href="/index.html">Enter</a></h1>');
     res.end();
     break;
   case '/index.html':
     fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(err, data){
        if (err) return send404(res);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': path == 'json.js' ? 'text/javascript' : 'text/html'})
        res.write(data, 'utf8');
        res.end();
     });
    break;
   case '/write.html':
     fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(err, data){
        if (err) return send404(res);
        res.write(data, 'utf8');
        res.end();
     });
   break;
  case '/post':
     console.log(req.toString());
     socket.broadcast.emit('user', {state: 'PHP Post', userid: 'PHP'});
     res.writeHead(200);
     res.end();
   break;

  default: send404(res);
}
}),

send404 = function(res){
   res.writeHead(404);
   res.write('404');
   res.end();
};

server.listen(843);

// socket.io 
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Regular socket.io events
```

Comment: i think there's some confusion. on checking up the docs of socket.io, they say that 'broadcast' broadcasts the event to all the sockets, except the socket on which it is called. Now which is the socket that you want to use, that is my confusion....

Comment: Yeah, I understand this. My issue is that the `socket.broadcast.emit('user', {state: 'PHP Post', userid: 'PHP'});` part, can't work because socket.io has not yet been required. But if I require socket.io before I define my server, it doesn't have a server to listen on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I require socket.io before I setup the server?

That part is pretty easy; at the top of your file, do something like:

```javascript
var http = require('http')
, url = require('url')
, fs = require('fs')
, socketIO = require('socket.io')  // <-- added line
, server;
```

and at the bottom:

```javascript
var io = socketIO.listen(server);
```

The problem is, in your `POST` handler, you're using `socket.broadcast.emit`, but `socket` isn't defined. Are you trying to send a message to *all* Socket.IO users? If so, you can use `io.sockets.emit`; I'd probably do something like this:

```javascript
var http = require('http')
, url = require('url')
, fs = require('fs')
, server
, io;

...

case '/post':
   console.log(req.toString());
   io.sockets.emit('user', {state: 'PHP Post', userid: 'PHP'});
   res.writeHead(200);
   res.end();
 break;

...

io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

If you're trying to send data to a single socket, or every socket except for a particular one (which is how you'd normally use `socket.broadcast`), you'll somehow need to map HTTP requests to Socket.IO sockets; [using sessions for this is common](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/).